# Bootstrap Modal Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i need help with my modal it just will not display. i can't seem to find what is wrong.
below is the code

```
 <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span><img src="img/logo.png"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cotton Board of Zambia</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="search" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>


    </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
 <table id="maintable" >
     <tr>
         <td>
            <table align="left" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td><p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#reglog" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Register & Login</a></p></td>
                    <td>
                    <!--register/login modal-->
                        <div class="modal hide fade in" id="reglog"  style="display: none; " >
                        <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4>Cotton Board of Zambia</h4><br>
                        <h6>Login Here</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form>
                            <label>Some text</label>
                            <input type="text">

                            </form>


                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">close</button>
                        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>  
                        </div>


                        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
                        <script src="/js/modal.js"></script>  



                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
         <td>
             <table align="right" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div><h3>Our Location</h3></div>
                  <div id="map">
                     <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 200px; height: 300px;"></div>
                   </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
   <div><hr/></div>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy;  2013</p>
  </footer>
</div> <!-- /container -->        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.js"><\/script>');</script>

    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <script>
        var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
        (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.src='//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
    </script>
</body>
```

from the little knowledge i have on HTML 5 seems like the code should work.
kindly help me figure out why the Modal will not display in the browser.
i also added the link as suggested and downloaded Modal.js but the modal still will not show in my browser. Kindly Help.

Comment: Where's the anchor that makes the modal appear when you click on it, and I think you also need the data-toggle attributes on the modal.

Comment: I added the following

    `<td><p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#reglog" class="btn btn-     primary btn-large">Register & Login</a></p></td>`

and also added

  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
       <script src="/js/modal.js"></script>  `

The Modal still will not show.

Comment: Can you update your question with that code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your modal from this:

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="reglog"  style="display: none;" >
```

to this:

```
<div id="reglog" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Bootstrap will automatically take care of hiding and displaying the modal for you, so you don't need to include the`style="display:none;"`.

Here is a link to the modals in the documentation for Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Comment: Nothing still, it still hasn't worked. is there a particular order to import javascript files?

Comment: The way you imported your js files looks fine.  Are you loading in the css for bootstrap?  Add `role="button`' to your `href`

Comment: Actually, put the js at the bottom near the `</body>` tag.  The javascript file may also be called `bootstrap-modal.js`, not `modal.js`.

Comment: You are loading in jquery twice, it looks like versions 1.7.1 and 1.10.1 there.  Remove version 1.10.1 and put version 1.7.1.  You are also loading in bootstrap.min.js which includes modal.js, so you can delete modal.js.  Update your answer with your current code after you make those changes if it still doesn't work.  Are you getting any javascript errors in your browser's console?